# Giving imshow a custom list of yaxis labels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to give pyplot.imshow() a list of values that aren't necessarily linear to use as y-axis labels. The truncated list is:

```
run_numbers = array([815676, 815766, 815767, 815768, 815769, 815770, 815771, 815772,
       815773, 815774, 815775, 815776, 815777, 815778, 815779, 815780,
       815781, 815783, 815784, 815785, 815786, 815789, 815790, 815792,
       815793, 815794, 815795, 815796, 815797, 815798, 815799, 815800,
       815801, 815802, 815803, 815804, 815805, 815806, 815807, 815808,
       815809, 815811, 815812, 815813, 815814, 815815, 815816, 815817,
       815818, 815819, 815820, 815821, 815822, 815823, 815824, 815825,
       815826, 815827, 815829, 815830, 815831, 815832, 815833, 815834,
       815835, 815836, 815837, 815838, 815839, 815841, 815842, 815843,
       815844, 815845, 815846, 815847, 815848, 815849, 815851, 815852,
       815853, 815854, 815855, 815856, 815857, 815858, 815859, 815860,
       815861, 815863, 815864, 815865, 815866, 815867, 815869, 815870,
       815871, 815872, 815873, 815874, 815875, 815876, 815877, 815878])
```

My image looks like this:

[image]

At first glance, this seems fine. But imshow isn't using the values from the list, instead it's using a linear range from `815676` to the max value of the list. I've tried a few different things:

`plt.imshow(np.array(profiles), aspect='auto', vmin=-5, vmax=20, extent=[0,500,max(run_numbers), min(run_numbers)])`

The above code gave the image above, which makes sense given what I put in extent.

Is there a way to tell imshow to use the values in the list as the yaxis label? I've tried `ax.yticklabels` and `ax.ytick`, but those also give a linear progression of numbers instead of the list values.

Please let me know how I can clarify my question if there's any confusion. I can also provide an example data set if my question isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting the extent go between 0 and the number of labels minus 1, and then use `plt.yticks(range(N), run_numbers)` would set the labels. As there are about 100 labels, this would look very crowded, which could be mitigated by setting a large figure size and a small font. Or the labels could be set every with steps, e.g. steps of 10:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

run_numbers = np.array([815676, 815766, 815767, 815768, 815769, 815770, 815771, 815772, 815773, 815774, 815775, 815776, 815777, 815778, 815779, 815780, 815781, 815783, 815784, 815785, 815786, 815789, 815790, 815792, 815793, 815794, 815795, 815796, 815797, 815798, 815799, 815800, 815801, 815802, 815803, 815804, 815805, 815806, 815807, 815808, 815809, 815811, 815812, 815813, 815814, 815815, 815816, 815817, 815818, 815819, 815820, 815821, 815822, 815823, 815824, 815825, 815826, 815827, 815829, 815830, 815831, 815832, 815833, 815834, 815835, 815836, 815837, 815838, 815839, 815841, 815842, 815843, 815844, 815845, 815846, 815847, 815848, 815849, 815851, 815852, 815853, 815854, 815855, 815856, 815857, 815858, 815859, 815860, 815861, 815863, 815864, 815865, 815866, 815867, 815869, 815870, 815871, 815872, 815873, 815874, 815875, 815876, 815877, 815878])
N = len(run_numbers)
profiles = np.random.randn(N, 501).cumsum(axis=1)
plt.imshow(profiles, aspect='auto', extent=[0, 500, N-1, 0])
plt.yticks(range(0, N, 10), run_numbers[::10])
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

With

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 16))
plt.imshow(profiles, aspect='auto', extent=[0, 500, N-1, 0])
plt.yticks(range(N), run_numbers, fontsize=8)
```

It could look like

[image: plot with small text]